# how to change the dimensions of a histogram depicted by plt.hist() as figsize is not an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram with a series using numpy array.

```
n,bins,patch = plt.hist(ser,bins=10, color='green', alpha=0.8, label='Value', edgecolor='orange', linewidth=2)
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('No of bags', size='x-large')
plt.xlabel('Money in US $', size= 'x-large')
```

IT is working well but the size is spo small. I tried using `olt.hist(figsize=(8,8))` but it throws error as expected.

How can I increase the size of my histogram figure?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8)) #change your figure size as per your desire here
n,bins,patch = plt.hist(ser,bins=10, color='green', alpha=0.8, label='Value', edgecolor='orange', linewidth=2)
....
....
```

To change the background color and the border color:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8),facecolor='red',edgecolor='blue')
```

Comment: how do I change the background and border color?

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing this though. Adding these 2 lines before my question code

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
his=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

``
```