# How to change the size of histograms in Python?

Tags: python, histogram

[image]
I am trying to create a histogram but the values seem to be very small, so the size of the histogram is also small. What can I add to make it bigger?
This is the code that I have:

```
plt.hist(my_data["Happiness Score"], bins=15, edgecolor ='white') 
#x and y labels:
plt.xlabel("Frequency")
plt.ylabel("Happiness Score")
textstr= 'Mean = 5.375734\nS.D =1.145010\nn = 158'
plt.text(40,50, textstr)
plt.axvline(x=5.375734,color='red',linestyle="dashed", label='mean')
plt.axvline(x=5.3757348 + 1.145010,color='green',linestyle="solid", label='S.D.')
plt.axvline(x=5.375734 - 1.145010,color='green',linestyle="solid")
plt.legend(loc='center right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: show your answer

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))`
 does this solve?

Comment: are you talking about something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352904/how-to-change-the-dimensions-of-a-histogram-depicted-by-plt-hist-as-figsize-is

Comment: @ombk I just added a picture of what I had in the beginning. I have tried implementing your code and it does make the histogram size bigger, but all the other things like labels and text don´t appear anymore. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes indeed i gave a huge rescaling, just try 7 by 7 maybe it will look better

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way is to use the figure(figsize) command.
You can play with the values of the size however you like.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
```